# trigger on the buttons in the slider slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I need to click on the custom arrows, what would the slider work. I know that there is a trigger in JQuery or something, but what can i do in react ?
You can see api slick-slider on this link https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows
[image]
..................................................................................................................................................................

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "red" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{ ...style, display: "block", background: "green" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}

export default class CustomArrows extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Custom Arrows</h2>

        // CLICK HERE
        <div><span>arrows<span><span>arrows<span></div>

        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slick-next')[0].click()
```

but I do not know if it is good to use in react